# First parameter to event handler

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I have some event handlers registered inline with my markup (deprecated, I know) like

```
 span id="..." onclick="foo(p1,p2,p3)"
```

how can I access the "event" object in the event handler function `foo`? Changing the above to

```
 span id="..." onclick="foo(event,p1,p2,p3)"
```

and then using it in `foo` like:

```
function foo(e,p1,p2,p3)
{
   if (!e) e = window.event;
}
```

seems to work but I don't see it documented anywhere so I am wary of using it. In other words, is the **first** parameter to a **inline** event handler always the *event* object *if* it is named as such in the `onclick=...` markup? Is this cross-browser so it can be safely used? And if it is not named as such (as in my first example), the parameters are treated like regular parameters and the event object is not passed?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding your code.

The string that you put in the inline handler is a normal piece of Javascript code.  It does not need to be a single function call; it can even contain multiple statements (separated by semicolons, as usual)

The code in the inline handler will be given a variable called `event` which refers to the event object.

When you write `onclick="foo(event,p1,p2,p3)"`, you're making a regular function call, and  passing the values of four variables named `event`, `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` as parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).  This seems to line up with your example.  However, there is some mention of this not working the same way in IE, so you have to check whether the first argument (event object) is defined and if not use window.event.

Another reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event).  I frequently find MDC to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ran a few tests in Firefox (3.5.8/linux) and here's what I've come up with. I was unaware of 'event' being used like in example 2, but it seems to work correctly in Firefox. However, it is NOT the case that the first variable passed to a function is always the event. 'event' seems to be registered in some global object, but I can't seem to determine which one. (It's not document, or window :P)

The line of code that you have in the foo function

```
if (!e) e = window.event;
```

is basically how you have to catch events in Internet Explorer anyway, so it will work in IE and Firefox for sure. And yes, therefore, if you are not passing a variable called 'event', as in your second example, the parameters will be treated as normal parameters, and the event object will not be passed.