# Why does this setup of event handler not work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom-events

Here is my html file `/tmp/test/test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="../js/my.js" defer>
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onchange" event to an input element.</p>   

    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname">
    <p>When you leave the input field, a function is triggered which transforms the input text to upper case.</p>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is my javascript file `/tmp/js/my.js`, but the setup of event handler doesn't work. why does it not work, and what shall I do to make it work?

```
function myFunction1(input) {
    input.value = input.value.toUpperCase();
}

document.getElementById("fname").onchange =  myFunction1;
```

If I replace the content of my Javascript file with

```
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("fname");
    x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}

document.getElementById("fname").onchange =  myFunction2;
```

The event handler works. I wonder why there is such a difference between the two methods?

Which way is preferred to specify the setup of event handler, in an external Javascript file or in html file?

Comment: The first parameter of an event handler is the `Event` object; not your `<input>` (which would be `this`).

Comment: @Xufox and that's how I know I've been at work too long today :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work has nothing to do with the script being in an external file. It is because you are assuming that a reference to the DOM object is being passed to the function as an argument (`input`), which it is not. `input` is actually a reference to the event. Event handlers that are set up using object properties (`onchange`, etc.) or via the more modern and standards-based `.addEventListener()` are automatically passed a reference to the event that was invoked as the callback function's first argument.

Your second version works because you are not relying on the argument for your reference to the DOM object and are correctly getting a reference to the DOM object with `document.getElementById("fname")`. But, in reality, you don't need to do anything special to get a reference to the DOM object that triggered the event, as that object will be bound to the `this` keyword within the callback function.

Beyond that, you should really move away from setting up events via event properties like `onchange`, etc. because that approach limits you to setting up only one event handling function per event. Instead use modern standards using **[`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**

Lastly, to change text content to all upper case, you don't even need JavaScript as that can be done solely with CSS.

See the example below that shows all of this:

```js
// Get your reference to DOM objects that you'll need just once, when the DOM is available
// And, set up events following modern standards:
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("change", myFunction);

// Event handlers are automatically passed a reference 
// to the event as the handler's first argument.
function myFunction(evt) {
  // Inside of an event handler for a DOM object, you can always
  // reference the DOM object that triggered the event via the target property
  // of the event (evt.target in this case) or, even simpler via the "this" keyword.
  console.log("Event: " + evt.type.toUpperCase()  + " was triggered by: " + this.nodeName + " " + this.id + " " + evt.target);
  this.value = evt.type;
}
```

```css
/* You don't need JavaScript to convert content to upper case */
#fname { text-transform:uppercase; }
```

```html
<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onchange" event to an input element.</p>   

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname">
<p>When you leave the input field (just hit TAB after inputting some data), the CHANGE event callback function is triggered.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am following this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/18893556/156458, where a reference to a DOM object is passed to the event handler function `check()`. Why does `check()` not expect to accept an event instead?

Comment: See [First parameter to event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2414081/4642212). Event attributes are very different.

Comment: @Tim That example uses HTML attributes to set up event handling, which is a 20 year old way of doing it that should no longer be used. That approach isn't referencing the function, it is directly invoking it and, in that approach, the event is not automatically passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get the DOM object from the event argument, instead of `document.getElementById("fname")` in my second way? If yes, is it a better way than `document.getElementById("fname")`?

Comment: @Tim Yes, you can with `evt.target`. But, if you look at my updated answer, you'll see that you don't need to do anything to get the reference because `this` will be bound to the DOM object that triggered the event. This is preferred because it requires no extra effort to get the reference.